# how to make the tbody children size same with the 1st tbody created after the thead

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

hi i have a problem with this.
i want to ask how to make the tbody children size can be same with the size the 1st row after the thead?

here my code..
please help me with it.. you can edit my fiddle or give an answer

```js
    var theadFlag = 0;
    var thdeadData = "";
    $(document).on('click','#input_check',function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
 
    if(theadFlag == 0) { theadData ='<tr>'
                                    +'<th>Nama Karyawan</th>'
                                    +'<th>Tanggal</th>'
         +'<th>Cost Center</th>'
                                    +'<th>Jam Mulai</th>'
                                    +'<th>Jam Selesai</th>'
                                    +'<th>Status Lembur</th>'
                  +'<th>Total Jam</th>'
         +'<th>Tugas</th>'
                                    +'</tr>' 
                               }
                     else 
                       {
                       theadData = ""
                       }
             
             var nama    = $('input[id="nama_check"]').val(),
                 bagian  = $('input[id="tanggal_check"]').val(),
                 cost    = $('input[id="cost_check"]').val(),
                 mulai   = $('input[id="start"]').val(),
           selesai = $('input[id="end"]').val(),
                 status  = $('input[id="status_check"]').val();
           total   = $('input[id="total_jam"]').val(),
     tugas   = $('input[id="tugas_check"]').val(),
                         
               $('tbody #body').append('<table id="check_data">'
                                  + theadData
                                  +'<tr>' 
                                    +'<td>'+$("#nama_check").val()+'</td>'                           
                                    +'<td>'+$("#tanggal_check").val()+'</td>'
                                    +'<td>'+$("#cost_check").val()+'</td>'
                                    +'<td>'+$("#start").val()+'</td>'
                                    +'<td>'+$("#end").val()+'</td>' 
                                    +'<td>'+$("#status_check").val()+'</td>'
                                    +'<td>'+$("#total_jam").val()+'</td>'
         +'<td>'+$("#tugas_check").val()+'</td>'
                                  +'</tr>'
                               + '</table>');
                      theadFlag = 1;
            });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myMd4" class="md4">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="md4-content" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div id="data">
      
  <table border="1" style="margin-left:50px">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <form action="../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php" id="form_check" method="post" name="form_check">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Nama Karyawan</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="text"  id="nama_check" type="text" name="nama_check" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase"> </td>
    <td width="10" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Tanggal</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="text"  id="tanggal_check" type="text" name="tanggal_check" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Jam Mulai</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime" style="float:left"/></td>
 
    <td width="100" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Jam Selesai</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="time" id="end" name="logouttime" style="float:left"/></td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Status Lembur</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><select name="option2" id="option2" onchange="Choose1(this)" style="float:left">
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="istirahat">istirahat</option>
      <option value="tanpa istirahat">tanpa istirahat</option>
    </select><input type="text" name="status_check" size="8" readonly="readonly" id="status_check" style="text-transform:uppercase"  /></td>
    <td width="10" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Total Jam</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="text"  id="total_jam" type="text" name="total_jam" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Cost Center</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="text"  id="cost_check" type="text" name="cost_check" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase" ></td>
    <td width="10" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
    <td width="150">Tugas</td>
    <td width="10">:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="text"  id="tugas_check" type="text" name="tugas_check" size="25" style="float:left" ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </td>
                <td width="300">
                <label class="button" name="input_check" id="input_check" style="height:35px; width:40px" />CLICK HERE</label>
             <label  class="button" name="edit_karyawan" id="edit_karyawan" style="height:35px; width:40px"  />b</label>
                <label  class="button" name="delete_karyawan" id="delete_karyawan" style="height:35px; width:40px; " />c</label>
                <label name="tutup" id="tutup" class="tutup" style="height:35px; width:40px;"/>d</label>
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>

                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <p align="center"><strong>Test</strong></p>
                <table id="check_data" class="check_data" style="font-size:12px; margin-left:70px ">
                  <tbody id="body"> 
                  </tbody>    
                  </table>
                  </td></tr></table>
                
                
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              <script>
             function Choose1(data) {

             document.getElementById ("status_check").value = data.value;

             }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several invalid html tag closing. I thing the proper way to do that is append `tr` instead of a whole `table`.

```js
var theadFlag = 0;
var thdeadData = "";
$(document).on('click', '#input_check', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (theadFlag == 0) {
    theadData = '<tr>' +
      '<th>Nama Karyawan</th>' +
      '<th>Tanggal</th>' +
      '<th>Cost Center</th>' +
      '<th>Jam Mulai</th>' +
      '<th>Jam Selesai</th>' +
      '<th>Status Lembur</th>' +
      '<th>Total Jam</th>' +
      '<th>Tugas</th>' +
      '</tr>';

    $('#body').append(theadData)
  }


  var nama = $('input[id="nama_check"]').val(),
    bagian = $('input[id="tanggal_check"]').val(),
    cost = $('input[id="cost_check"]').val(),
    mulai = $('input[id="start"]').val(),
    selesai = $('input[id="end"]').val(),
    status = $('input[id="status_check"]').val();
  total = $('input[id="total_jam"]').val(),
    tugas = $('input[id="tugas_check"]').val(),

    $('#body').append(

      '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + $("#nama_check").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#tanggal_check").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#cost_check").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#start").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#end").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#status_check").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#total_jam").val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $("#tugas_check").val() + '</td>' +
      '</tr>');
  theadFlag = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myMd4" class="md4">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="md4-content" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div id="data">

      <table border="1" style="margin-left:50px">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table border="1">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <form action="../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php" id="form_check" method="post" name="form_check">
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Nama Karyawan</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><input type="text" id="nama_check" type="text" name="nama_check" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase"> </td>
                        <td width="10" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Tanggal</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><input type="text" id="tanggal_check" type="text" name="tanggal_check" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Jam Mulai</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td><input type="time" id="start" name="logintime" style="float:left" /></td>

                        <td width="100" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Jam Selesai</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><input type="time" id="end" name="logouttime" style="float:left" /></td>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Status Lembur</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><select name="option2" id="option2" onchange="Choose1(this)" style="float:left">
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="istirahat">istirahat</option>
      <option value="tanpa istirahat">tanpa istirahat</option>
    </select><input type="text" name="status_check" size="8" readonly="readonly" id="status_check" style="text-transform:uppercase" /></td>
                        <td width="10" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Total Jam</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><input type="text" id="total_jam" type="text" name="total_jam" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Cost Center</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><input type="text" id="cost_check" type="text" name="cost_check" size="25" style="float:left; text-transform:uppercase"></td>
                        <td width="10" style="border-left:hidden; border-right:hidden"></td>
                        <td width="150">Tugas</td>
                        <td width="10">:</td>
                        <td width="150"><input type="text" id="tugas_check" type="text" name="tugas_check" size="25" style="float:left"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </form>
                </td>
                <td width="300">
                  <label class="button" name="input_check" id="input_check" style="height:35px; width:40px">CLICK HERE</label>
                  <label class="button" name="edit_karyawan" id="edit_karyawan" style="height:35px; width:40px">b</label>
                  <label class="button" name="delete_karyawan" id="delete_karyawan" style="height:35px; width:40px; ">c</label>
                  <label name="tutup" id="tutup" class="tutup" style="height:35px; width:40px;">d</label>


                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p align="center"><strong>Test</strong></p>
                  <table id="check_data" class="check_data" style="font-size:12px; margin-left:70px ">
                    <tbody id="body">
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                  <script>
                    function Choose1(data) {

                      document.getElementById("status_check").value = data.value;

                    }
                  </script>
```

Comment: tag closing at where?
in my html script or in my jquery function @Parvez Rahaman

Comment: @MinervazMine in your html. I have removed them